# declaring a promise in angularJS with named success/error callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to do something very similar to the $http service. From my understanding $http return a promise object.

When using it the syntax is :

```
$http(...).success(function(data)) {
   //success callback
}).error(function(data)) {
   //error callback
})
```

I would like to do just the same but consider my API is GetUserProfile, so I wish to have the syntax :

```
GetUserProfile(...).success(function(data) {
   // success callback
}).error(function(data)) {
   // error callback
})
```

how can I accomplish that using a promise ?

Comment: You could take a look at how angular.js implements [this in `$http`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ng/http.js#L701).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The nice thing with open-source is that you can read the source. Here's how the $http service does it:

```
  promise.success = function(fn) {
    promise.then(function(response) {
      fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
  };

  promise.error = function(fn) {
    promise.then(null, function(response) {
      fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
  };
```

Comment: Response interceptors are [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/api/ng/service/$http#response-interceptors-deprecated-) in 1.3+, but the same concept still applies.  Use something like: `promise.success = function (fn) { return promise.then(fn); }); promise.error = function (fn) { return promise.then(null, fn); });`

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the $q service and create and return your own promise in GetUserProfile:

```
function GetUserProfile() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    // success condition
    if (!true) {
        deferred.resolve('data');
    // error condition
    } else {
        deferred.reject('error');
    }

    promise.success = function(fn) {
        promise.then(fn);
        return promise;
    }

    promise.error = function(fn) {
        promise.then(null, fn);
        return promise;
    }

    return promise;
}

GetUserProfile()
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: I am aware of it.. but still the success/error syntax used in $http will not apply here. or maybe it will ? is the success/error syntax is by default used when a promise returned ?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. No, the promise object doesn't have success and error methods by default.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added the success/error methods to the promise object.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need change source code.
Angular provide a way to change any service in angular include $q.

$provide.decorator is perfect for your requirement 
here is my code.

put it at app.module('...').config

```
$provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate) {
  function httpResponseWrapper(fn) {
    return function(res) {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty('data') && res.hasOwnProperty('status') && res.hasOwnProperty('headers') && res.hasOwnProperty('config') && res.hasOwnProperty('statusText')) {
        return fn(res.data, res.status, res.headers, res.config, res.statusText);
      } else {
        return fn(res);
      }
    };
  };
  function decorator(promise) {
    promise.success = function(fn) {
      return decorator(promise.then(httpResponseWrapper(fn)));
    };
    promise.error = function(fn) {
      return decorator(promise.then(null, httpResponseWrapper(fn)));
    };
    return promise;
  };
  var defer = $delegate.defer;
  $delegate.defer = function() {
    var deferred = defer();
    decorator(deferred.promise);
    return deferred;
  };
  return $delegate;
});
```

Comment: Most responses for how to do this breaks the ability to chain promises together whereas your solution preserves that capability, I prefer your answer.