# How to mock an angular $http call and return a promise object that behaves like $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, angular-mock

Is there a way to return an HttpPromise (or something similar) to mimic a call to `$http`? I want to set a global variable that indicates whether the real HTTP request is made or whether a fake HttpPromise object is returned with fake data.

For example, I have a service that is similar to this:

```
angular
  .module('myservice')
  .factory('MyService', ['$http', function($http) {
      return {
       get : function(itemId) {
         if (isInTestingMode) {
           // return a promise obj that returns success and fake data
         }
         return $http.get("/myapp/items/" + itemId);
       }
    };
 } ]);
```

And in my controller, I have a call to the aforementioned service that looks similar to this:

```
        // Somewhere in my controller

        MyService.get($scope.itemId)
           .success(function(data) {
              $scope.item = data;
           })
           .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.notFound = true;
           });
```

I'm trying to **not** change the controller code; I want the `success` and `error` chaining to still work when in my "isInTestMode". 
Is it possible to fake an `HttpPromise` in the way that I described in the service?

---

Below is a revised edition of the "MyService" above (a snippet) containing a `success` and `error` on the promise object. But, how do I execute the `success` method?

```
        return {
           get : function(itemId) {
             if (isInTestingMode) {
                var promise = $.defer().promise;
                // Mimicking $http.get's success 
                promise.success = function(fn) {
                  promise.then(function() {
                     fn({ itemId : "123", name : "ItemName"}, 200, {}, {});
                  });
                  return promise;
                };
                // Mimicking $http.get's error 
                promise.error = function(fn) {
                   promise.then(null, function(response) {
                     fn("Error", 404, {}, {});
                   });
                   return promise;
                };
                return promise;
             }
             return $http.get("/myapp/items/" + itemId);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797209/how-can-i-extend-q-promise-in-angularjs-with-a-succes-and-error) is similar to what I was asking.

However, I wanted a way to mock my service call so that fake data could be returned instead of issuing a true HTTP request call. The best way to handle this situation, for me, is to use angular's `$httpBackend` service. For example, to bypass a GET request to my "items" resource BUT to *not* bypass GETs of my partials/templates I would do something like this:

```
angular
   .module('myApp', ['ngMockE2E'])
   .run(['$httpBackend', function($httpBackend) {
      $httpBackend
        .whenGET(/^partials\/.+/)
        .passThrough();
      $httpBackend
        .whenGET(/^\/myapp\/items\/.+/)
        .respond({itemId : "123", name : "ItemName"});
}]);
```

See [this documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) for more information on $httpBackend.

Answer (score 18):

Just use the `deferred` method of the `$q`service

```
    var fakeHttpCall = function(isSuccessful) {
    
      var deferred = $q.defer()
    
      if (isSuccessful === true) {
        deferred.resolve("Successfully resolved the fake $http call")
      }
      else {
        deferred.reject("Oh no! Something went terribly wrong in your fake $http call")
      }
      
      return deferred.promise
    }
```

And then you can call your function like an `$http` promise (you have to customize whatever you want to put inside of it, of course).

```
    fakeHttpCall(true).then(
      function (data) {
        // success callback
        console.log(data)
      },
      function (err) {
        // error callback
        console.log(err)
      })
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how the success or error is forced to execute. I updated my question with an expanded example based on your comment. I don't see how I could force the success method from within the "get" in the MyService.

Comment: you just need to set the `deferred.resolve(result)` and then return the promise if you want to simulate the success.... or set `deferred.reject(error)` if you want to simulate a failure

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work as `deferred.promise` doesn't provide `success()` and `error()` for chaining, like $http. See this answer for example for how to achieve that - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19747182/404099.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski `success()` and `error()` are not used anymore.
Promises gives you the `then( success, error )` construct, which is more powerful and can be chained to infinite.
See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @domokun probably I wasn't clear enough. In the answer the second part shows call to `fakeHttpCall(true).success()`. This should fail, since `fakeHttpCall` returns `deferred.promise`. The later indeed defines `then()`, as you mentioned in the comment, but not `success()`.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski you are totally right, I was preaching right but writing wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

I finally [found a way using jasmin](http://jasonmore.net/unit-testing-http-service-angular-js/). `$httpBackend` was no option for me, as there were also non-$http-methods I needed mock on the same service. I also think that the controller test needing to specify the url is not perfect as imho the controller and its test should not need to know about it.

Here is how it works:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  mockSvc = {
    someFn: function () {
    },
    someHttpFn: function () {
    }
  };

  // use jasmin to fake $http promise response
  spyOn(mockSvc, 'someHttpFn').and.callFake(function () {
    return {
      success: function (callback) {
        callback({
         // some fake response
        });
      },
      then: function(callback) {
         callback({
         // some fake response, you probably would want that to be
         // the same as for success 
         });
      },
      error: function(callback){
        callback({
         // some fake response
        });             
      }
    }
  });

  MyCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    MyActualSvc: mockSvc
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your FakeHttp class:

```
var FakeHttp = function (promise) {
    this.promise = promise;
    this.onSuccess = function(){};
    this.onError = function(){};
    this.premise.then(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
};
FakeHttp.prototype.success = function (callback) {
    this.onSuccess = callback;
    /**You need this to avoid calling previous tasks**/
    this.promise.$$state.pending = null;
    this.promise.then(this.onSucess, this.onError);
    return this;
};
FakeHttp.prototype.error = function (callback) {
    this.onError = callback;
    /**You need this to avoid calling previous tasks**/
    this.promise.$$state.pending = null;
    this.promise.then(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
    return this;
};
```

Then in your code, you would return a new fakeHttp out of the promise.

```
if(testingMode){
    return new FakeHttp(promise);
};
```

The promise must be asynchronous, otherwise it won't work. For that you can use $timeout.

Answer (score 0):

easy peasy!

You can do it using [angular-mocks-async](https://github.com/amoldavsky/angular-mocks-async) like so:

```
var app = ng.module( 'mockApp', [
    'ngMockE2E',
    'ngMockE2EAsync'
]);

app.run( [ '$httpBackend', '$q', function( $httpBackend, $q ) {

    $httpBackend.whenAsync(
        'GET',
        new RegExp( 'http://api.example.com/user/.+$' )
    ).respond( function( method, url, data, config ) {

        var re = /.*\/user\/(\w+)/;
        var userId = parseInt(url.replace(re, '$1'), 10);

        var response = $q.defer();

        setTimeout( function() {

            var data = {
                userId: userId
            };
            response.resolve( [ 200, "mock response", data ] );

        }, 1000 );

        return response.promise;

    });

}]);
```